# Alternative to using HttpGetAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP .NET MVC 4 project

I have something like this

```
   public class FooController : ApiController
        {

            [HttpGet]
            public models.Terminal read(long id)
            {

            }
        }
```

Is there an alternative to using the attribute? Is there somewhere else in the Project I can specify that its a HttpGet request method rather than in the Controller?

Comment: Could you give some context? What is it you're attempting to do?

Comment: The same functionality of using the HttpGet attribute, without having to use the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Well, not really.

Using the `[HttpGet]` attribute is a form of metaprogramming as you're trying to declare some additional information about the method.  The Controller **is** the interface between your clients and your API, so this is the place it belongs.  The Controller is responsible for handling HTTP requests and executing code appropriately, so an attribute that provides additional information (or a constraint) on how HTTP requests are handled belongs in the Controller.  So even if there was some way to achieve the same functionality without an attribute, you really shouldn't do it.

Comment: Omitting the attribute in Web API 2 does not default to a GET request.

Comment: Yeah, good catch. I'm too used to MVC's Controller behavior.  I'll edit the answer.